# CSS issue when zooming

Tags: html, css

I wrote CSS for screen size bigger than 1100 px. When I press ctrl and +(plus) sign and zoom in the center container of the page can't wrap. It breaks suddenly.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer_footer_bottom">
    <div class="center">
        blabla balaa blabalblabla
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    #outer_footer_bottom{
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        background: #8ac53f;
        height: 26px;
        padding: 16px 0 0 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }

    .center {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Ctrl +/- doesn't increase screen size, it changes the zoom level

Comment: @slash197 yes i have issue with zoom level.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using media queries to get responsive web design

Check the following articles to get started

http://mediaqueri.es/

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: i don't need to make it responsive..i have issue with zoom level.. :)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in your code.

your `"outer_footer_bottom"` div has width 100% (not fixed) 
and the `"center"` div has width 1000px (fixed)

lets suppose you have zoom level 100% and your window size is approximately 1200px this means that your `"outer_footer_bottom"` div has width 1200px and size of `"center"` div is 1000px.

ok when you increase the zoom level the window size decreased and size of `"outer_footer_bottom"` will become lesser than 1000px. but size of `"center"` div remain unchanged i.e 1000px.

so that is the reason you are facing  this problem.

**SOLUTION 1:** change the "outer_footer_bottom" div's width to fixed (e.g 1000px or 1200px)

**SOLUTION 2:** change the "center" div's width to unfixed (e.g 100% or 90%)

Answer (score 0):

```
.center {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Remove width:1000px from the style of center class.

Comment: But there is already a width defined for the outer div. So it will not make any problem.

Comment: @slash197 You can try it using the above code and verify. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing problem with your code. When you increase or decrease the zoom level it is having 100% width in `#outer_footer_bottom` and showing scroll-bar when your zoom level less than 1000px defined in `.center`

Comment: i don't have problem with scroll bar, i have problem with #outer_footer_bottom, its color doesn't wrap on 100% width...:)

Comment: its color is same http://jsfiddle.net/clink/Jjp8U/ but is seem to be hidden but scroll up and down staying at that scroll bar to see that text. It's a height problem you should define the height.